# Android -- onCreate() of extended class of MainActivity not called

Tags: java, android

At one point I included the listeners and methods for MediaPlayer in MainActivity and it worked. Then I decided MainActivity is so large that I should move the code to an extended class (or should I not use an extended class).

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    . . . 
    private muPlayer muPlay;
    . . .
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        . . .
        muPlay = new muPlayer();
        . . .
        // May be called from here or from a listener
        muPlay().play();
        . . .
    }
    protected int getLayoutId(){
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```

The extended class

```
public class muPlayer extends MainActivity implements
        OnCompletionListener, OnClickListener {
. . .
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( getLayoutId() );

        thisPath    = thisContext.getFilesDir().getPath();
        . . .
        muToggle = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.butToggle);
        . . .
        muToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
        muRewind.setOnClickListener(this);
        progBar.setOnClickListener(this);
        progBar.setClickable(false);
        . . .
    }
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        . . .
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        . . .
    }
    public void play( ) {
        . . .
    }
    . . . 
}
```

And MainActivity is identified in AndroidManifest.xml, not the muPlayer.

```
<application
    . . .
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

OnCreate() in muPlayer is not being called. What am I missing? Or is my whole approach wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want an instance of `muPlayer` to be created, you need to declare that in the manifest.

Comment: Your `muPlayer` should not extend `MainActivity`. Creating an instance of an activity with the `new` keyword is always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have extend MainActivity in muPlayer so MainActivity is Parent Class.
Call muPlayer in MainiFest

```
<application
. . .
<activity android:name=".muPlayer">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to declare muPlayer in your mainfest. Add following entry in maifest:

```
<activity android:name=".muPlayer "/>
```